# prove a theorem of a trapezoid that is divided by a straight line

Tags: geometry

I have been working on this theorem for a while, but can't prove it. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

Theorem: For a trapezoid ABCD, in which a is the area of the trapezoid ABFE that is the same as the area of trapezoid EFCD, the following relationship is true:

AB<sup>2</sup>-EF<sup>2</sup>=EF<sup>2</sup>-DC<sup>2</sup>

[image]

Comment: This seems as if it shouldn't be true, especially in the extreme case when $CD$ is near $0$, but perhaps this is a way to approach the question...

Comment: abiessu, you made a good point. Then how can this be a theorem?

Answer (score 3):

Let $h_1$ be the height of  $ABFE$ and $h_2$ be the height of $EFCD$. Since $ABFE$  and $EFCD$ have the same area, we have
$$ \frac{AB + EF}{2}h_1 =\frac{EF+CD}{2}h_2 $$
So we have, multiplying both sides by 2:
$$ (AB + EF)h_1 =(EF+CD)h_2 $$
On the othe hand, using similar triangles, we have 
$$\frac{AB-EF}{h_1} = \frac{EF-CD}{h_2} $$
Multiply both equations, we get 
$$ (AB + EF)(AB - EF) =(EF+CD)(EF-CD)$$
That is
$$ AB^2-EF^2=EF^2-DC^2$$.